# How to set read timeout with RestCypherEngine Query

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I've been trying to figure out how to prevent Read Socket timeouts when making queries using RestCypherEngine in my java application. Here is the class ...

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

@Autowired
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor;

@Autowired
RestAPIFacade gd;

@Autowired
RestCypherQueryEngine engine;

@Override
public void addActivityObjectToGraph(List<Activity> activities) {
    taskExecutor.execute(new ProcessActivity(activities));
}

//Runnable to process the activities as they come in..
class ProcessActivity implements Runnable {
    private List<Activity> activities;

    public ProcessActivity() {
    }

    public ProcessActivity(List<Activity> activities) {
        this.activities = activities;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        log.info("Processing Activity Collection of size: " + activities.size());

        for (Activity activity : activities) {
            Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();

            props.put("activityid", activity.getActivityID());
            props.put("objecttype", activity.getTargetObjectType());
            props.put("objectid", activity.getTargetObjectID());
            props.put("containertype", activity.getContainerObjectType());
            props.put("containerid", activity.getContainerObjectID());
            props.put("activitytype", activity.getType());
            props.put("userid", activity.getUserID());
            props.put("creationdate", activity.getCreationDate());


            try (Transaction tx = gd.beginTx()) {

                params.put("props", props);
                params.put("userid", activity.getUserID());

engine.query("match (p:Person{userid:{userid}}) create unique (p)-[:created]->(a:Activity{props})", params);

                params.clear();
                tx.success();

            } catch (RestResultException rre) {
                log.info(rre.getLocalizedMessage());
            } catch (CypherExecutionException cee) {
                log.info(cee.getLocalizedMessage());
            }catch(Exception e) {
                    log.info(e.getLocalizedMessage());

            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

When the application just starts, I get fine results from the query exceution but after a while, I start getting a bunch of exception messages like these

```
2014-06-20 09:33:24.070  INFO 12902 [taskExecutor-15] --- c.y.n.services.impl.UserServiceImpl      : java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
2014-06-20 09:33:24.446  INFO 12902 [taskExecutor-94] --- c.y.n.services.impl.UserServiceImpl      : java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
2014-06-20 09:33:24.501  INFO 12902 [taskExecutor-46] --- c.y.n.services.impl.UserServiceImpl      : java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
2014-06-20 09:33:24.512  INFO 12902 [taskExecutor-47] --- c.y.n.services.impl.UserServiceImpl      : java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
```

I read in several articles that this could be solved by setting the org.neo4j.rest.read_timeout property to something like a 100 seconds but I have no idea how I should go about setting this value. I added the setting to my application.properties file (I am running a Spring Boot gradle application by the way) but this seems to have no effect.

I am running a Neo4j community server (v2.1.2) on a Centos 6 server with 30GB RAM which I think should be sufficient even for production grade systems. What do I need to do to get rid of these errors?

Thanks.

Comment: How much memory do you assign to neo4j? Adding too much memory to java app without tuning garbage collection might be harmful and show exactly the behaviour you are experiencing (server pausing to do GC)

Comment: I assigned a max of 24GB to Neo4J process. Is that too much. I have been looking for documentation with regards to server tuning and not come up with much in this regard.